# The Vitest mock for @inertiajs/vue3's usePage is not functioning as expected during testing

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs, vitest

I am writing test cases for VueJS application files. In one of the files i am using inertia's `usePage`, code:

```
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
const page = usePage();
const path = computed(() => {
  return page.url.includes('test-url');
});
```

In test file i am mocking the usePage as:

```
vi.mock('@inertiajs/vue3', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...vi.importActual('@inertiajs/vue3'),
  usePage: () => ({
    url: '/test-url'
  })
}));
```

But when running the test i am getting error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') in page.url.includes('test-url');`

Any leads on how to fix this?

I expect the value of usePage mock to be passed to page in the actual component. i.e page.url should be `test-url`

Comment: It looks like it should work. You can debug what page is

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to change the order of imports inside your testing?
if you are importing you component before the import of @inertiajs/vue3,like:

```
import YourComponent from '../YourComponent.vue';
import {usePage} from @inertiajs/vue3;
```

change to

```
import {usePage} from @inertiajs/vue3;
import YourComponent from '../YourComponent.vue';
```